# Inserting List of ContentVersions and ContentDocumentLinks at the same time

Tags: bulkification, contentdocumentlink

I'm looping through a list of records, creating content versions, adding to a list of content versions and then inserting the list of content versions.

I then need to create a content document link to a related record so the document is visible on both records.

I'm trying to avoid SOQL in for loops so I'm unsure how to create the document link with the related parent record Id.

An example of what I'm trying to do below:

```
List<sObject> listOfsobjects = [SELECT Id, parentId, someOtherField FROM sobject WHERE....];

List<ContentVersion> listOfContentVersions = new List<ContentVersion>();

for(sObject a : listOfsobjects){
  ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion();
  contentVersion.Title = 'Title';
  contentVersion.VersionData = blob;
  contentVersion.PathOnClient = 'Title.pdf';
  contentVersion.FirstPublishLocationId = a.Id;

  listOfContentVersions.add(contentVersion);
}

insert listOfContentVersions;

List<ContentDocumentLink> listOfdocumentLinks= new List<ContentDocumentLink>();

for(ContentVersion contentVersion : listOfContentVersions){
  ContentDocumentLink documentLink = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
  documentLink.ContentDocumentId = 'contentVersion.documentId';
  documentLink.LinkedEntityId = 'the a.parentId from the sobjects list';
  documentLink.ShareType = 'V';

  listOfdocumentLinks.add(documentLink);
}

insert listOfdocumentLinks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to requery the inserted ContentVersions to get the parent ContentDocumentId

```
// Build xref of sobjects by Id
Map<Id,SObject> sobjectsById = new Map<Id,Sobject> (
   [SELECT Id, parentId, ... ]);  
List<ContentVersion> listOfContentVersions = new List<ContentVersion>();
for (SObject a : sObjectsById.values()) {
   ...  build the ContentVersion
}

insert listOfContentVersions;
List<ContentDocumentLink> listOfdocumentLinks= new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
for (ContentVersion cv: [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentID, FirstPublishLocationId  
                         FROM ContentVersion 
                         WHERE Id IN :listOfContentVersions] {
  listOfdocumentLinks.add(new ContentDocumentLink(
       ContentDocumentId = cv.ContentDocumentId,
       LinkedEntityId = sObjectsById.get(cv.FirstPublishLocationId).ParentId,
       ShareType = 'V'
       ));
 }
 insert listOfdocumentLinks;
```

Notes:

1. You can construct the object and add to the list in one statement as shown; this makes for conciser code.
2. Personally, I prefer naming collections simply as plurals : `contentDocumentLinks`, `contentVersions` as `listOf...` adds little value

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense but the LinkedEntityId needs to be the parent Id of the original record that the version belongs to. We have a child object of Contact and create the content version on the child object and then create a link to the contact (parent object).

Comment: ah, I missed that, fixed answer by adding a map

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thank you